# ie9 spacing - css not working as it should

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, font-face

Hi might be a simple one for someone.

I have finished working on this website and in ie9 there is a lot of line height issues - i don't even know if line height is the right word - spacing seems to imply letter spacing.

The easiest way to explain my issue is with screen shots.

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

[image]

Why is the 3rd one (ie9) so out?

url for the website is http://www.geckowebsolutions.co.uk

Could it be the font .eot is rending differently to the otf?

If so how can I work around this?

DanSiop

Answer (score 2):

Change your headers to tell IE9 to follow the modern norms :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Do the 3 changes : the doctype, the html element *and* the meta.

Comment: should that be a setting that is used with other browsers as well?

Comment: It works with all browsers. Non IE ones ignore `X-UA-Compatible`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply but its not happening, i have made the threee changes you have recommended, i have cleard the cache and nothing has changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it's happening (trouble shooting in IE sucks) but it's your.breadcrumbs CSS that is being affected. Quick and dirty solution is to add an IE conditional.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
    .breadcrumbs{top:11px;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```